# How to submit a form without jumping to the top of the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a list of conversations (multiple messages grouped by sender).

I have a reply text box under each conversation.

Once I submit the reply (fill in some text in the text box and hit the reply button) the page refreshes/redirects and jumps to the top of the page.

Is it possible to submit the form which adds the reply in to the displayed conversation without jumping to the top of the page?

In my view I have

```
<% @messages.each do |from, message| %>
 <p><%= from %></p>
 <% message.each do |msg| %>
  <p><%= msg.content %></p>
 <% end %>

 <%= form_for( @message ) do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :content %>
 <%= f.submit "Reply" %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller I have

```
def create
...
 if @message.save
  redirect_to @business, notice: 'Reply sent.'
 else
  redirect_to @business, notice: 'Reply could not be sent.'
 end
end
```

Comment: Use jQuery for that. :)

Comment: You're redirecting the page on your controller. It will always be on top. If you really wanna to stay where you were before try using jQuery/Ajax

Comment: if there is no problem with redirection, try to redirect to your desire page on desire portion with `anchor` (e.g. `redirect_to business_path(@business, :anchor => "message")`). Otherwise use `ajax` to submit form.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
form_for(@message), remote: true do |f|
```

Then in your controller (action create has to be post in routes)

```
if @message.save
  render json: { succ: true, notice: 'Reply sent.'}
else
  render json: { succ: false, notice: 'Reply could not be sent.' }
end
```

After that you have to handle it with javascript, easiest way is  to use jQuery and do:

```
$('#container').on('ajax:success', function(event, data){
  if (data.succ) {
    // handle your success somehow, like show a new field
    // you can use data.notice
  } else { 
    // something went wrong
  }
})
```

Hope that helps

Take a look a those jQuery functions:

```
$('#foo').hide() // hides the element (e.g. form)

$('#bar').val('') // on input sets value to empty

$('#msg_container').append('<p>form</p><p>message</p>')
// adds html to the end of the container

$('#notice').html(data.notice)
// changes the contents of the element (e.g. displaying notice)
```

That should be enough to handle the comments, you can find more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Oh and dont forget you can pass more parameters via json if you like, for example:

```
render json: { succ: true, notice: 'Reply sent.', from: someone, msg: text}
```

Comment: Thats a big help. Thank you. My jQuery is terrible. Can I ask you to help with the handling of the success and failure? I just want the newly created reply to get added to the end of the list thats being displayed.

Comment: Added a few sample jQuery functions that might prove helpful.